# How to fix psql SYNTAX error when trying to migrate using a tar file?

Tags: postgresql, terminal, syntax, migration, psql

The results below show the issue that I am running into. Please let me know what think I am doing wrong. i am trying to migrate a PostGreSQL db to another server. After doing the pg_dump on the 1st server and getting the tar file over to this new one I am running into this issue when trying to get the data uploaded onto the new db.

```
[postgres@host ~]$ psql newdb < newdb.tar
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "toc" at character 1
LINE 1: toc.datREVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM postgres;
        ^
GRANT
GRANT
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE auth_group FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "auth_group" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "auth_group" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE auth_group_permissions FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "auth_group_permissions" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "auth_group_permissions" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE auth_permission FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "auth_permission" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "auth_permission" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE auth_user FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "auth_user" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "auth_user" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id" at character 1
LINE 1: id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE auth_user_groups FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "auth_user_groups" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     START WITH 1
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE auth_user_user_permissions FROM postgr...
        ^
ERROR:  relation "auth_user_user_permissions" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_account FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_account" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_account" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_account_organizations FROM p...
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_account_organizations" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_budget FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_budget" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id" at character 1
LINE 1: id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_budget_categories FROM postg...
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_budget_categories" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_budget_comments FROM postgre...
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_budget_comments" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     START WITH 1
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_budget_restricted FROM postg...
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_budget_restricted" does not exis
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: REVOKE ALL ON TABLE dashboard_category FROM postgres;
        ^
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_category" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "dashboard_category" does not exist
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH" at character 7
LINE 1: START WITH 1
              ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1:     id integer NOT NULL,
        ^

invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \.
invalid command \.
invalid command \.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "" at character 1
LINE 1: 3 Account User
```

Comment: There are are alot more lines of errors I Just could not fit them all in this post.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably dealing with a “TAR format dump” that was created with `pg_dump -F t`.

To restore such a dump, you don't use `psql` (which is used to restore plain format dumps), but `pg_restore`:

```sh
pg_restore -d newdb newdb.tar
```